# Backup router config using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, cisco, cisco-ios

Im using python and paramiko.
Im trying to backup a network device router using python. Below is my script.
However  im getting error

```
import paramiko
import sys
import time

HOST = "10.11.214.143"
USER = "admin"
PASS = "passwd"


client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
  print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST

#copying config to tftp
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('copy nvram:startup-config tftp: 10.11.214.144')
print stdout.read()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    client1.exec_command('copy nvram:startup-config tftp:')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 436, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 716, in open_session
    timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 800, in open_channel
    raise SSHException('SSH session not active')
SSHException: SSH session not active
```

Comment: I don't know if it's your case but I know for sure that for some Cisco routers the' exec_command()' method is not working, at least for some versions of Paramiko. I had to use the lower level 'invoke_shell()' API to interact with them.

Comment: Can you please advise the modifications required in my script

Comment: Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490989/how-to-keep-ssh-session-not-expired-using-paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490989/how-to-keep-ssh-session-not-expired-using-paramiko)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach; I saw exec_command() failing against some routers, but I can't assure it fits your problem:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import time

HOST = "10.11.214.143"
USER = "admin"
PASS = "passwd"


client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST

console = client1.invoke_shell()
console.recv(65535)

console.send("copy nvram:startup-config tftp: 10.11.214.144\n")

# Adjust sleep as it's needed by your command
time.sleep(.5)
console.recv(65535)

# Eventually quit gracefully with the right command
console.send("quit\n")
time.sleep(.5)

client1.close()
```

Comment: `copy nvram:startup-config tftp: 10.11.214.144\r\n     ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nR2>`

Comment: Got error while copying..  i think syntax or we might also have to specify the file name for copying

Comment: Address or name of remote host and Destination file name can we specify these 2 parameter in command itself.
It asks for this parameter when manually executing this command

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't help you for the specific command(s) to issue on the remote...

Comment: can we specify the paramter in script itself

Comment: You can specify the file name in the command like `tftp://10.11.22.33/filename`
It will still ask you for confirmation, but you can suppress it using the command `file prompt quiet`
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3792/51961